# JDialog layout issues

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jdialog

I'm using a `JDialog` to create a customized dialog box for my Java project. I'm having issues with the layout at the moment. It seems each `JLabel` I add to the dialog goes over the existing one. Do I need to add some sort of `JPanel`?

I also seem to have a issue with the size. I set it too 500x500 but why does it only goes as large as the text width?

```
JDialog processData = new JDialog(f1, "TItle goes here");
JLabel centretext = new JLabel("Look at me im centre!");
JLabel leftext = new JLabel("LOok at me im left");
JLabel righttext = new JLabel("LOok at me im right");
processData.setVisible(true);
processData.add(centretext);
processData.add(lefttext);
processData.add(rightext);
processData.toFront();
processData.setSize(500,500);
processData.setLocation(500,500);
processData.pack();
```

Comment: You need to read up on and learn how to use layout managers.

Comment: Couldn't find duplicate in time.... Lord this gets asked a lot.

Comment: *"I also seem to have a issue with the size. I set it too 500x500 but it only goes as large as the text width?"*  Don't use 'magic numbers' for the size.  If a border is required for the components, add them to a `JPanel` and set an `EmptyBorder` to it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Have to book mark this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JDialog` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which means, it will only show a single component in any of the five available positions, all the others get ignored.

Consider using a different layout manager.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details